# Whitelist pages to skip purgecss on tailwind next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, css-purge

I have Next.js project that use Tailwind CSS, and I want to make a UI Documentation by iterating over the config from `tailwind.config.js`.

The problem is, it works on development, but when i try to build on production mode, the classes that i iterate from `tailwind.config.js` doesn't loaded. It means the classes was purged by purgecss.

How can i whitelist the page that skip to use purgecss? I mean, not safelisting by selector, but by page. Example, i want to whitelist all pages on directory `./src/pages/docs` to skip purgecss. Is it possible? I need your help

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [Excluding purge page folder tailwind css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112957/excluding-purge-page-folder-tailwind-css)?

Comment: yeah but there's misunderstanding on the questions, so the answer don't solve my problems @juliomalves

Comment: @SutanNasution Please don't create two open questions asking the same thing. In this situation either update your original question to clear up any misunderstanding, or delete your original question before posting its replacement.

Comment: i think we can just answer it :-)

Comment: so sorry, i'm new on stack overflow, it's my first question